# python subfolder import chaos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, python-import, python-module

suppose I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── a.py
│   └── b.py
└── main.py
```

The files have the following content:

b.py:

```
class BClass:
    pass
```

a.py:

```
from b import BClass
```

main.py:

```
from A import a
```

If I run `python3.3 A/a.py` or `python3.3 B/b.by`, there are no errors. However, if I run `python3.3 main.py`, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from A import a
  File "/tmp/python_imports/A/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from b import BClass
ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

Changing the import-line in a.py to `import A.b` works, but obviously `python3.3 A/a.py` will fail then. I am not actually interested in running `python3.3 A/a.py` but I want the module to be importable from multiple locations. Therefore a.py should import b.py regardless of where a.py is imported.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Make a package and use absolute imports. See http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/ for a good introduction.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in the `A` directory?

Comment: Is `b.py` really importing from itself (`from b ...`) or is that a typo?

Comment: @Alfe: whoops, you're correct. The filenames were swapped, I corrected them. Thanks! I tried adding a `__init__.py`, but it does not make a difference.

Comment: @rmartinjak: Well, here we go. On the website you found it says : "[...] There’s a very, very old method of doing imports (“implicit relative imports”) wherein one would write from multibase import Multibase instead, but this is gone in python 3." However, I wonder what my mistake is. `from A.b import BClass` should just work fine then, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you're not interested in running `pyhon A/a.py`, don't do it.

Comment: @rmartinjak: Fair enough, I was just wondering about the different contexts in importing, which still looks very strange to me. Thank your for the link, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the `__init__.py` I mentioned in my comment which is mandatory for packages, you need to import the sibling module relatively:

```
from .b import BClass
```

Then it also works in Python 3.

Alternatively you can of course import the full name:

```
from A.b import BClass
```

But then your module isn't relocatable as easily within your package tree.

In neither way, though, you are able to use `a.py` as a standalone.  To achieve this you would need to surround the `import` statement with `try`/`except` and try a different version in case the first one fails:

```
try:
  from .b import BClass
except ValueError:
  from b import BClass
```

But that is understandable.  In a larger system, modules might depend on other modules *somewhere* in the package, otherwise they maybe should not be part of a package but standalone.  And if there are such dependencies, using a module as if it was a standalone will of course be a problem.

Comment: Using `from.b import BClass` works for `python3.3 main.py`, but running `python3.3 A/a.py` gives: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .b import BClass
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import ` (sorry for that strange indentation!). Is this going to hurt when I import A from another location?

Comment: I added an explanation why this problem exists and offered a hacky workaround using `try`/`except`.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds logical to me. I'm afraid I have to come up with another question: If a folder `B` containing a file `test.py` is added to the scenario and `test.py` contains the line `from ..A import a`, `python3.3 test.py` fails with exactly the same error that I posted above ("...Parent module '' not loaded...") What do I have to change the import in `test.py` to?

Comment: Are you talking about a separate package named `B` located besides the package `A`?  It should just use `from A import a` then.  Do not forget the `B/__init__.py` to declare the directory as a package.

Comment: aaah... `from A import a` works, if I do the import in `main.py`. Can I use `B/test.py` as a standalone or is that also not possible?

Comment: You will then have to `import B.test` or `from B import test` of course.  If you again try to run `test.py` as a standalone, then Python will fail to find the package `A` as it isn't in the directory of `test.py`.  You can then set `PYTHONPATH` accordingly to point to your `A` package.

Comment: E. g.: ``PYTHONPATH=`pwd` python3 B/test.py``

Comment: Those python modules are driving me crazy! And everybody is saying C++ is hard! So, without messing with `PYTHONPATH`, it is not possible to import modules located in root-folders?

Comment: You are trying a hack, and for that you need to do hacky things like setting `PYTHONPATH` somewhere.  The proper way to do it is _not using modules in packages as standalones_.  Also, if you properly install a package (like your `A`), then it will be at e. g. `/usr/local/lib/python/...` and therefore will be found from any Python script without having to set the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: If a module (deep) in a package is supposed to also be a standalone, it should not be part of that package, as I said before.  If you want to do that anyway, maybe providing a small wrapper script, shipped along with your package, is a good idea then:  It imports that specific module from the package and calls its `main()` function properly.

Comment: I understand that and I really don't want to run scripts in _actual_ modules. However, what is the best way to organize unit-tests? I don't like the idea of having them directly in the root-folder and it looks hard having them in their own test-folder! (accepting your answer in the meantime as the question is solved, thank you for that :) )

Comment: I put my unit tests directly in the module files they are supposed to test.  But now we are drifting to the next question.  Maybe ask that! :-)

Comment: I didn't think of that, but that's a great idea. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need an `__init__.py` file (empty will be just fine) in the `A` directory. Otherwise, python won't recognize it as a package.

Now you're A is a package, you should use either absolute imports or explicit relative imports. In this case, in `A/a.py` either use `from A.b import BClass` or `from .b import BClass`.

Comment: I added the `__init__.py` but it the problem remains! It looks like python is actually doing the import of `A` in `main.py` but fails to the the subsequent import of `BClass` in `a.py`

Comment: Yes, now you're A is a package, you should use absolute imports or explicit relative imports. In this case, in A/a.py either use `from A.b import BClass` or `from .b import BClass`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I upvoted it. However, I'm going with Alfe's answer as he was more elaborate.